# Add Dropbox Files To UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, dropbox

I am trying to load my dropbox files into a UITableView but they are not showing up. I did every step from registering my app on dropbox.com and implementing the session delegate in my app. Here is my code can anyone tell me whats wrong with it. Im pretty sure i declared everything correctly but i cant seem to find the problem. Also i know its not a connection issue because i added an NSLog and it logs the files.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>

@interface testViewController : UITableViewController <DBRestClientDelegate>
{
    DBRestClient *restClient;
    NSMutableArray *dropboxURLs;
}
@end

#import "testViewController.h"

@interface testViewController ()

@end




@implementation testViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (DBRestClient *)restClient {
    if (!restClient) {
        restClient =
        [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return restClient;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dropboxURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
            if (!file.isDirectory)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", file.filename);
                [dropboxURLs addObject:file.filename];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client
loadMetadataFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Error loading metadata: %@", error);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return dropboxURLs.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FileCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [dropboxURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: You said you logged the files -- where did you do that?  Did you log dropBoxURLs to see if it has anything in it?  It appears from your error messages, that your array is empty.

Comment: @rdelmar Hi i logged the files right before i added them to the array at: NSLog(@"%@", file.filename);
                [dropboxURLs addObject:file.filename];

Comment: Try logging dropboxURLs.count in the numberOfRowsInSection method to see what it returns

Answer (score 0):

Reload the table view after you add things to the dropboxURLs array.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Hi when i added that i got:2012-08-17 11:55:46.938 Share Me[5987:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3acfe6c3 0x34d7e97f 0x3ac4a055 0x60065 0x39d4ab81 0x39d2f93b 0x39d46e17 0x39d02f2b 0x39bdde9b 0x39bdda39 0x39bde975 0x39bde353 0x39bde161 0x39bddfc1 0x3acd3aed 0x3acd1de1 0x3acd2137 0x3ac4539d 0x3ac45229 0x3780231b 0x39d538f9 0x59ce9 0x352bab20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this immediately after your addObject call:

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Hi also when i added this i got: 2012-08-17 11:55:46.938 Share Me[5987:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3acfe6c3 0x34d7e97f 0x3ac4a055 0x60065 0x39d4ab81 0x39d2f93b 0x39d46e17 0x39d02f2b 0x39bdde9b 0x39bdda39 0x39bde975 0x39bde353 0x39bde161 0x39bddfc1 0x3acd3aed 0x3acd1de1 0x3acd2137 0x3ac4539d 0x3ac45229 0x3780231b 0x39d538f9 0x59ce9 0x352bab20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
            if (!file.isDirectory)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", file.filename);
                [dropboxURLs addObject:file.filename];
            }
        }
    }
    [self. tableView reloadData];
   }
```

Don't forget to set delegate and datasource of UITableView to self.

Answer (score 0):

- we have to load data from DropBoxRoot
- After MetaData is loaded ,reload the tableview

> - (void)viewDidLoad{
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>     dropboxURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>     [self loadData];
>     }

```
-(void) loadData{
if ([DBSession sharedSession].root == kDBRootDropbox) {
    photosRoot = @"/";//can specify any folder like /Photos,/Public etc
}
[self.restClient loadMetadata:photosRoot withHash:photosHash];
}


- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

photosHash = metadata.hash;

NSArray* validExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jpg", @"jpeg",@"png",@"txt",@"pdf",@"doc",@"mp3",@"mp4", nil];
for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents) {

    NSString* extension = [[child.path pathExtension] lowercaseString];

    if (!child.isDirectory && [validExtensions indexOfObject:extension] != NSNotFound) {
        [directory addObject:child.filename];
    }else{
        [allFileAndDirectory addObject:child.filename];
    }
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```